# Getting a dict from a list Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a JSON that looks like this:

```
"payment_methods": [{
    "payment_type": "CC",
    "cardSubType": "AX",
    "card_number": "377777684182882",
    "expiration_month": "01",
    "expiration_year": "2018",
    "security_code": "",
    "cvv2": "",
    "name": {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Smith"
    },
    "billing_address": {
        "country": "United States",
        "address_line1": "666 SUNSET BLVD",
        "address_line2": null,
        "city": "Anaheim",
        "state": "California",
        "zip_code": "92808",
        "phone": "0123456789"
    },
    "payment_amount": "",
    "payment_percentage": ""
}]
```

What need to do is the save the `billing_address` into a variable to later use the values inside that dict. 
Would `billing_address in payment_methods` work?

Is there a better/pythonic way to do this?

Comment: It is inside an array. So, you might want to do something like `addr = json_object["payment_methods"][0]["billing_address"]`

Comment: This doesn't appear to be valid JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to obtain billing_address property?

```
import json

#Fix the null, normalize the json since is not a valid json
null = None
data = json.dumps({"payment_methods": [{
    "payment_type": "CC",
    "cardSubType": "AX",
    "card_number": "377777684182882",
    "expiration_month": "01",
    "expiration_year": "2018",
    "security_code": "",
    "cvv2": "",
    "name": {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Smith"
    },
    "billing_address": {
        "country": "United States",
        "address_line1": "666 SUNSET BLVD",
        "address_line2": null,
        "city": "Anaheim",
        "state": "California",
        "zip_code": "92808",
        "phone": "0123456789"
    },
    "payment_amount": "",
    "payment_percentage": ""
}]})

data = json.loads(data)

billing_address = data["payment_methods"][0]["billing_address"]

print billing_address
```

Comment: Just used this part billing_address = data["payment_methods"][0]["billing_address"] and worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would separate these into 2 dictionaries. The second dictionary, with the address, would be stored in the variable `billing_address`

It would look like this:

```
payment_methods = {
                  "payment_type": "CC",
                  "cardSubType": "AX",
                  "card_number": "377777684182882",
                  "expiration_month": "01",
                  "expiration_year": "2018",
                  "security_code": "",
                  "cvv2": "",
                  "first_name": "John",
                  "last_name": "Smith",
                  "payment_amount": "",
                  "payment_percentage": ""
                  }
billing_address = {
                      "country": "United States",
                      "address_line1": "666 SUNSET BLVD",
                      "address_line2": "null",
                      "city": "Anaheim",
                      "state": "California",
                      "zip_code": "92808",
                      "phone": "0123456789"
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a JSON string, so parse it into a Python dictionary. The (almost valid) string represents a dictionary, but it needs to be enclosed in `{` and `}`. On the assumption that the json string is returned from some other API, this can be done with [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) like this:

```
json_string = '{{{}}}'.format('''"payment_methods": [{
    "payment_type": "CC",
    "cardSubType": "AX",
    "card_number": "377777684182882",
    "expiration_month": "01",
    "expiration_year": "2018",
    "security_code": "",
    "cvv2": "",
    "name": {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Smith"
    },
    "billing_address": {
        "country": "United States",
        "address_line1": "666 SUNSET BLVD",
        "address_line2": null,
        "city": "Anaheim",
        "state": "California",
        "zip_code": "92808",
        "phone": "0123456789"
    },
    "payment_amount": "",
    "payment_percentage": ""
}]''')
```

Now the string can be parsed into a dictionary using the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#module-json) module, and the billing address details by accessing the appropriate keys and list indexes within the dictionary. Assuming you want only the billing details for the first payment method in the list of (potentially many) payment methods:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

payment_methods = json.loads(json_string)['payment_methods']
billing_address = payment_methods[0]['billing_address']

>>> pprint(billing_address)
{u'address_line1': u'666 SUNSET BLVD',
 u'address_line2': None,
 u'city': u'Anaheim',
 u'country': u'United States',
 u'phone': u'0123456789',
 u'state': u'California',
 u'zip_code': u'92808'}
```